# How to replace a a href value using pug and javascript?

Tags: pug

Let's say I have this a href tag.

```
a(href=#) Link
```

Now I have 2 radio buttons

```
  input(type='radio', name='Link1') 
  |  Link 1
  input(type='radio', name='Link2') 
  |  Link 2
```

How do I update the a href based on radio button selected value? By default, href is #.

If Link 1 is selected, href = "http://www.domain1.com"
If Link 2 is selected, href = "http://www.domain2.com"

Comment: Pug is just a server-side preprocessing language for HTML. This kind of functionality must be handled on the front-end with javascript. I recommend editing this question to show the HTML instead of Pug, and retagging as `javascript`.

Comment: ok thanks. Solved already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pug is just a server-side preprocessing language for HTML. This kind of functionality must be handled on the front-end with javascript.